# Issues serving PHP from URL subfolder of Sinatra app running via Passenger/Apache?

Tags: php, apache, sinatra

We have a Sinatra app running in the domain root via passenger such as `http://rootdomain.com/`

We have some PHP pages we would like to serve in a subdirectory like so: `http://rootdomain.com/example`

The Sinatra app lives in a folder `/var/webapps/homepage` which is deployed to via mina/git.

Ideally, we would then place our PHP scripts in `/var/www/example` and have these pages served by Apache.

The method by which I am trying to do this is via Apache aliases:

**httpd.conf**

```
Alias /example/ /var/www/example
Alias /example /var/www/example
```

However, anything other than `http://rootdomain.com/example/index.php` returns a 404 (for example: http://rootdomain.com/example or http://rootdomain.com/example/`

My httpd.conf has a directive like so:

```
<Directory /var/www/example>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution was found here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/530958/apache2-with-passenger-and-subdirectory-with-file-listing

Which is incredibly and simply disabling Passenger for the specified folder, so as in the case above it would be:

```
<Location /var/www/example/> 
  PassengerEnabled off 
</Location>
```

Within the `<virtualhost>...</virtualhost>` block.